Kafka Producer sends message event after Future.get() TimeoutException
Here's the code:
@Override
public void send(Key key, Value value) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, key, value).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

Steps to reproduce:

Start sending an event.
Disable kafka container.
Waiting for TimeoutException.
Enable Kafka container.

Expected result: The message has not been sent.
Actual result: Message delivered to consumer.
I know that KafkaTemplate may use queue inside, and it sends async. Maybe it's something wring with timing properties? Thanks.

There's a retries property on the producer config that defaults to the max integer value. Have you tried setting that to zero if you expect nothing to send?
